# How can Split tag in XML and INSERT to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to split EC value and then `INSERT` into a table in SQL Server, but the first one `UPDATE` on this ROW.

My XML tag :

```
<Relations mfid="SubjectMaj_My">
   <Form EC="19" ETC="712" Value="temp1" />
   <Form EC="1" ETC="712" Value="temp2" />
   <Form EC="37" ETC="712" Value="temp3" />
</Relations>
```

when I `SELECT` in my table like this :

```
SELECT [SubjectMaj_My] 
FROM AB_Warehouse.dbo.Maless_Letters
```

I get value like this (some of them just one tag form but some of them can more than 1 tag form !):

```
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="6" ETC="712" Value="uy" Token="e29c2aeeb0a340818f460d47a7faa8a2" /></Relations>
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="47" ETC="712" Value="gg" Token="e773c5a4949c4b639b41f4f49a120845" /></Relations>
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="7" ETC="712" Value="aa" Token="87068cc61c2944a782fe6be9473f064c" /></Relations>
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="47" ETC="712" Value="asdsa" Token="742ca91fbd77424799084fa0c56e63c7" /></Relations>
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="6" ETC="712" Value="asdd" Token="8efbf5745d39459c8c23cf7bfc36bf75" /></Relations>
<Relations mfrid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="26" ETC="712" Value="ff" Token="b74d6ab0ffa642be98cf7972c9f1041a" /></Relations>
<Relations mfid="SubjectMaj_My"><Form EC="19" ETC="712" Value="temp1" /><Form EC="1" ETC="712" Value="temp2" /><Form EC="37" ETC="712" Value="temp3" /></Relations>
```

Comment: can you give an example of your table to insert and update? also, you need to give us sample code of what you have tried to do.

Comment: What attributes are identifiers, and what attributes should be updated?
Can you post the _expected result_ of running this query?

Comment: yes , each of <Relations> tag is one ROW of my result of running this query

Answer (score 1):

Next time please read [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I do not know your table, so you will have to adapt this, but you can give it a try:

```
SELECT l.SomeColumnToIdentifyTheRow
      ,frm.value(N'@EC',N'int') AS Form_EC
      ,frm.value(N'@ETC',N'int') AS Form_ETC
      ,frm.value(N'@Value',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Form_EC
FROM AB_Warehouse.dbo.Maless_Letters l
OUTER APPLY [SubjectMaj_My].nodes(N'/Relations/Form') A(frm);
```

This will take each row from your table and create a derived table out of each XML. This is done using `APPLY` in connection with XML's method `.nodes()`.

This will return all repeating elements separated in rows. From there we can read the attributes' values.